# how to dynamically add a control with validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

There is a button named "add another" in an aspx page, if user click the button, a new text box will be added with a RequiredFieldValidator.

i try to use the code like this:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox control = new TextBox();
        control.Text = "";
        control.ID = "txt2";
        divMy.Controls.Add(control);//divMy is the container of all the textbox

        RequiredFieldValidator rfv2 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        rfv2.ID = "rfv2";
        rfv.ControlToValidate = control.ID;
        rfv.ErrorMessage = "bbb";
        divV.Controls.Add(rfv2);//divV is the container of all validations.           
    }
```

It does not work. what the correct way to achieve this function?

Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying it does not work, you mean it cause some kind of error to appear or it does not validate correctly?

Remember that if you want those controls to be still visible after next postback, you must recreate them. I suppose that without additional code recreating the controls, it won't work correctly. You should save number of boxes somewhere (i.e.in hidden field) and recreate them in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`. `ID`s of the controls have also to be unique and should not change between postbacks.

You can get some more information about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx.